# GRUB from windows?

Tags: linux, windows, grub

So, basically, I have a dual boot setup with a windows drive partition and a linux drive partition, but I can only access the Windows partition and need Grub to get into Linux... which I need to get into Grub. Is there any fix for this?

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Better add details with, where useful, some screenshots.

Comment: Sounds like your dual boot setup is improper. Do you still have the directions you followed? Don't even have a PC to test, but someone else can likely point out what went wrong if you edit with that info.

Comment: Seems clear to me, the Ubuntu installer did not install Grub so now I can only boot into windows. But Grub can not be installed from windows, it only has linux versions as far as I know. Is there an alternative?

Comment: I think my dual boot setup is proper, one hard drive with a windows partition and an Ubuntu partition. But the Ubuntu installer did not install Grub like it's normally supposed to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few possibilities.

1. You installed ubuntu first and windows second, this leads to windows bootmgr overwriting grub on the mbr (if you're using mbr grub that is)

Solution: Reinstall grub, or reinstall Ubuntu.

2. You are using an EFI version of grub and probably bootmgr, these can coexist rather nicely. If you're not booting into grub the reason is that it is not selected as the default EFI boot option.

Solution: Select grub/linux as the default EFI boot option from the bios.

3. Grub is not an option in the EFI boot manager in the bios

Solution: Install grub on the mbr the good old fashioned way, and select the drive on which you wrote grub to mbr as the default boot device.

If none of the above work (though I'd be particularly surprised if that last one doesn't; it's usually my lazy way out of efi boot problems heh, always works for me) then there's something wrong with your installation of grub and you need to carefully install it the right way; manually. You can look up how to do all these things on your own.

If you cannot access your linux installation by selecting the correct booting option from the bios, there are live cds/dvds/usbs that you can use to bypass it instead. I imagine what you used to install ubuntu in the first place could work. At least you should be able to chroot your way in.